# Code from Coroutines callbackFlow is called only one time

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have function:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    override suspend fun checkIsPostLiked(userId: String, postId: String): Flow<FirebaseEventResponse> = callbackFlow {
            try {
            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(postCollection).document(postId).get().addOnSuccessListener {
                trySend(SuccessDocument(it))
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                trySend(ExceptionEvent(it))
            }.await()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            trySend(ExceptionEvent(e))
        }
        awaitClose { this.cancel() }
   }
```

When i want to use it second time code is not called. I tested another function with only *Log.d* inside and had the same problem.

Comment: await close expect to dispose/cancel something else otherthan the flow itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A flow is a type [that can emit multiple values sequentially](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow). An `addOnSuccessListener` or `addOnFailureListener` would emit their results just once. So what you probably want to use is a `suspendCancellableCoroutine` builder that can be used for one-shot requests.

Here's what that might look like:

```kotlin
override suspend fun checkIsPostLiked(userId: String, postId: String): FirebaseEventResponse = suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
        try {
            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(postCollection).document(postId).get().addOnSuccessListener {
                continuation.resume(SuccessDocument(it), null)
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                continuation.resumeWithException(ExceptionEvent(it))
            } 
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            continuation.resumeWithException(ExceptionEvent(e))
        }
    }
```

And you can call it in any coroutine scope (e.g viewModelScope) like so:

```kotlin
viewModelScope.launch {
  try {
    val isPostLiked = checkIfPostIsLiked(userId, postId)
  } catch(e: Exception) {
    // handle exception
  }
}
```

Side benefit: You don't have to use the `@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi` decorator ;).

##### EDIT

If you're using `await` then you're already using `Firestore` with coroutines. So there's no need to use any coroutine builder, just call the suspended function without the `addOnSuccessListener` and `addOnFailureListener`

```kotlin
override suspend fun checkIsPostLiked(userId: String, postId: String): FirebaseEventResponse = 
        try { 
          FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection(postCollection)
            .document(postId)
            .get()
            .await()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
```

Comment: OP is already calling [await](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/kotlinx.coroutines.tasks/com.google.android.gms.tasks.-task/await.html), which does pretty much this already AFAICT.

Comment: @Joffrey thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my answer.